# Неправильно вычисляет сумму

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано натуральное число `N`. Вычислить:

```
S=1+1/3+1/5+1/7+...+1/2*N+1
```

Код:

```
N = int(input("Введите число N: "))
S = 0
for i in range(1, N+1):
    S += 1/(N*2+1)
print(S)
```

Например ввожу `5`, должно получиться `2.174242424` но получается `0.4545454545454546`
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: В том, что при подсчёте нужно использовать переменную цикла `i`, а вы используете в подсчёте максимальное число `N`, а `i` нигде не используете.

Comment: Все правильно на каждой итерации получается число 0.09090909090909091 умножим на 5 = 0.4545454545454546

Answer (score 1):

```
N = int(input("Введите число N: "))
S = 0
for i in range(0, N+1):
    S += 1/(i*2+1)
print(S)
```